# Redirect customer to the page from where customer clicks for login Magento

Tags: magento

I want to redirect customer to the page from where customer clicks for login, like if a customer is on any category page and click on login then after login he must redirected to the category page.

I am doing this code in observer at `customer_login` event but when try to get before auth url then I got `customer/account/loginPost` instead of category url.

Code which I am using is:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'))
```

But this doesn`t redirect to any where while ouput comes as

```
 [before_auth_url] => /customer/account/loginPost/
 [after_auth_url] =>/customer/account/loginPost/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - Redirect back (similar to using setBeforeAuthUrl) when user creates a new account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779259/magento-redirect-back-similar-to-using-setbeforeauthurl-when-user-creates-a)

Comment: @scrowler its looks slimier but situation is diffrent.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure this from admin side.
Login into Magento admin side and change system configuration.
**`System > Configuration > Customer configuration > Login options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > No`**.
Customer will stay on the current page if "No" is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Hi friend you can do this way.

app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
//$session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getAccountUrl());

$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'your_url');
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this myself, hope this will help of others.

1. create observer and catch url before login. `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_login`

   ```
    <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_login>
           <observers>
               <ash_getref>
                   <class>ash_getref/observer_customer</class>
                   <method>getReferrerUrl</method>
               </ash_getref>
           </observers>
       </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_login>
   ```
2. And save referral value url in custom session variable in observer file.

   ```
   public function getReferrerUrl(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setReferrerUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()  : Mage::getUrl());  
   }
   ```
3. Then create observer for after login event i.e `customer_login`.

   ```
    <customer_login>
           <observers>
               <ash_getref>
                   <class>ash_getref/observer_customer</class>
                   <method>customerLogin</method>
               </ash_getref>
           </observers>
       </customer_login>
   ```
4. Then redirect in observer    .

   ```
   public function customerLogin(){
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getReferrerUrl());
               Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
               exit;
   }
   ```